# CRM 2011:How to change a Read only form into Editable form by using Plugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have one Case form which is resolved,and i want to edit the case form,how to do this in dynamic crm 2011 plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved cases can be reopened again by clicking on **Reactivat Case** button on the **Ribbon**.

If you tried this:

```
incident["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(1);
incident["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(0);
incident["incidentstagecode"] = new OptionSetValue(1);

_serviceProxy.Update(incident);
```

you'll get this exception which says:

```
"The object cannot be updated because it read-only"
```

**Update:** Thank you "Ckeller" for you note

To reopen a solved Case you can add this code to you're Plug-in:

```
SetStateRequest activateRequest = new SetStateRequest
    {
       EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("incident", new Guid("<Your Case GUId>")),
       State = new OptionSetValue(0),
       Status = new OptionSetValue(1)
    };
_serviceProxy.Execute(activateRequest);
```

Comment: I think you've tried to change the state with Update. This will no work. You have to use SetState.